# Problem using user-defined table type with generated database deployment script

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010, deployment, database-project

I'm having a strange issue with VS2010's database project not able to execute a generated deployment script that uses a user-defined table type in an SP's parameter list. I get the following error when executing the deployment script:

> Error SQL01268: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AppSearch, Line 36 Must declare the scalar variable "@platforms".

The **@platforms** variable here is a user-defined table type, that is defined simply like this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdList] AS TABLE 
(
    Id      uniqueidentifier
);
```

The stored procedure that I am creating looks like the following, which uses the UDDT as one of its parameters:

```
PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[AppSearch]...';


GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AppSearch]
    @nameContains           nvarchar(30),
    @descriptionContains    nvarchar(max),
    @isEditorsPick          bit,
    @dateAddedStart         datetime,
    @dateAddedEnd           datetime,
    @platforms              IdList      readonly
AS
begin
    select
        l.Id as [LibraryId],
        l.Name as [LibraryName],
        l.Description as [LibraryDescription],
        c.Id as [CategoryId],
        c.Name as [CategoryName],
        c.Description as [CategoryDescription],
        a.Id as [AppId],
        a.Name as [AppName],
        a.Description as [AppDescription],
        a.IsEditorsPick as [AppIsEditorsPick],
        a.DateAdded as [AppDateAdded],
        p.Id as [PlatformId],
        p.Name as [PlatformName],
        p.Architecture as [PlatformArchitecture]
    from
        Library l
        inner join Category c               on l.Id = c.ParentLibraryId
        inner join App a                    on c.Id = a.ParentCategoryId
        inner join AppSupportedPlatform px  on a.Id = px.AppId
        inner join Platform p               on px.PlatformId = p.Id
    where
            (@nameContains is not null and a.Name like '%' + @nameContains + '%')
        and (@descriptionContains is not null and a.Description like '%' + @descriptionContains + '%')
        and (@isEditorsPick is not null and a.IsEditorsPick = @isEditorsPick)
        and (@dateAddedStart is not null and @dateAddedEnd is not null and a.DateAdded between @dateAddedStart and @dateAddedEnd)
        and (@platforms is not null and p.Id in (select Id from @platforms))
end
GO
```

The deployment script gets executed using SQLCMD mode. Any ideas on why I'm getting the above error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I figured it out. Towards the end of my script, where I check if @platforms is not null, turns out that I can't do that check because it's not a scalar variable. I should have paid attention to the error message more, lol. Lesson of the day: TVP's are not scalar variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that a table type should act somewhat like a table. You can't say "if TABLE is NOT NULL" so why should you be able to say "if TABLE TYPE is NOT NULL"? I haven't used TVPs extensively, but how about checking that the TVP is not empty:

```
AND (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @platforms) AND p.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @platforms));
```

The latter might be enough (again that is more from lack of playing with TVPs than anything) or maybe:

```
AND (p.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @platforms) OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @platforms));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had just figured that out just now. UDDT's are not scalar types, and so the 'is not null' check is not valid since that requires scalar types.

I don't think I even need the check on if the @platforms variable, so I just removed it (for now).

Comment: Whether you need it depends on what behavior you want when the stored procedure is called without that parameter. If you just say `AND p.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @platforms)` what do you want to happen when it's empty? Do you want the check ignored or do you want 0 results?

Comment: I will want the check ignored actually. Thanks for the input. Much appreciated.